# is there any way to make pdf scrollable in the horizontal way?

Tags: iphone

I am showing a pdf in the web view and by default this has been showing in the vertical scroll way ,i just need it in the horizontal way scrollable ,Can it be done using the web view .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make it wider than the view.

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't work i changes its height and also width but it is vertical scrollable than too .
any other way ?